# Android passing value of array from async task to another class

Tags: android, arrays, android-asynctask, global-variables

I am trying to get an array from one async task class to another fragment class but I am getting a null pointer exception. I have seen many answers on here but none that I saw actually answered this question.

I tried returning the value from the async class task and I tried to make the array static but I have had no success.

These are the classes (I have highlighted where I am trying to get the value from and bring it to):

```
    public class DemoPreviewSongFragment extends DemoFragmentBase {
        // The DynamoDB object mapper for accessing DynamoDB.
       private final DynamoDBMapper mapper;
        public DemoPreviewSongFragment() {
            mapper = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getDynamoDBMapper();
        }

        SongPreviewCardsDataAdapter mCardAdapter;
        com.wenchao.cardstack.CardStack mCardStack;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                                 final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preview_song, container, false);
            mCardStack = (CardStack)view.findViewById(R.id.cardstackcontainer);
            mCardStack.setContentResource(R.layout.song_preview_card_layout);
            mCardStack.setStackMargin(20);

            new getSongsInCategory().execute();

/////////// WHEN TRYING TO REFERENCE THE STATIC ARRAY RESULT HERE I GET A NULL /////////// POINTER. I NEED THE ARRAY HERE SO I CAN PUT IT IN THE ADAPTER.   

            mCardAdapter = new SongPreviewCardsDataAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),0);
            mCardAdapter.add("test1");

            mCardStack.setAdapter(mCardAdapter);

            return view;
        }



//////////////////// THIS IS THE ARRAY I AM TRYING TO PASS /////////////////////
        public static PaginatedQueryList<SongDatabaseMappingAdapter> result;

        public class getSongsInCategory extends AsyncTask {

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

                SongDatabaseMappingAdapter songs = new SongDatabaseMappingAdapter();
                songs.setCategory("Rap");

                String userRatingQueryString = "5";

                Condition rangeKeyCondition = new Condition()
                        .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
                        .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withN(userRatingQueryString));

                DynamoDBQueryExpression queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression()
                        .withHashKeyValues(songs)
                        .withIndexName("Category-UserRating-index")
                        .withRangeKeyCondition("UserRating", rangeKeyCondition)
                        .withConsistentRead(false);

                result = mapper.query(SongDatabaseMappingAdapter.class, queryExpression);
                return result;
            }
    }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here why is that a null pointer when it should be a global (static) array? Is there a better way to be doing this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you have to understand the principle of `AsyncTask`, simply put, it runs some things on a different thread, not blocking the current thread, and by not blocking that means it will automatically go to the next line after you call `execute` not depending on the duration of the tasks in the asynk task and not waiting for the tasks to be completed.

In your case:

```
new getSongsInCategory().execute(); // here you call the task to generate the result
result.doSomething() // this line will be called before your task is completed, so the result won't be initialized => NPE
```

The way you should do it is using `Observer` pattern (callbacks). You set an observer to your AsyncTask to find out when it's done. When it's done it will notify the object that observes the task.

So an example could be something like this:

```
public class DemoPreviewSongFragment extends DemoFragmentBase implements AwesomeObserver {
 public interface AwesomeObserver {
     void theTaskIsDone(Object theTaskResult);
 }

 public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
... 
new GetSongsInCategory(this).execute();
```

//new best practice is 
    new GetSongsInCategory(this).executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
 }

```
@Override
theTaskIsDone(Object theTaskResult) {
    theTaskResult.doSomething();
    //In your case
      mCardAdapter = new SongPreviewCardsDataAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),0);
        mCardAdapter.add("test1");

        mCardStack.setAdapter(mCardAdapter);
}

public class GetSongsInCategory extends AsyncTask {
  private AwesomeObserver observer;
  public GetSongsInCategory(AwesomeObserver someone) {
      observer = someone;
  }
 // doInBackground ....and do things

 public void onPostExecute(Object object) {
    // at this point you know the task is done
   if(observer != null) 
     observer.theTaskIsDone(object);
    } 
 }
```

}

Now to avoid confusion, the parameters in `theTaskIsDone` & `onPostExecute` are just examples, and you can use whatever it works for your example.
This is really a generic way to go, you could also call from `onPostExecute` a method from the containing class of your async task, but this approach will work if you have inner async task or an async task in a separate java file.

Answer (score 2):

Set data to adapter in onPostexecute() method of AsynTask. You are getting exception because you are not getting any data is adapter. AsynTask performs operation in background and it may be the case you are using the values before AsyncTask is finished. So set adapter in onPostExecute.

```
doInBackground(){
}
onPostExecute(){

// use result array here and set it on adapter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Asynctask is asynchronous so the array is null.You can update the adapter when the asynctask completed by accessing in the OnPostExecute() method.

This is the code i have changed the logic now it will work.

```
public class DemoPreviewSongFragment extends DemoFragmentBase {
    // The DynamoDB object mapper for accessing DynamoDB.
   private final DynamoDBMapper mapper;
    public DemoPreviewSongFragment() {
        mapper = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getDynamoDBMapper();
    }

    SongPreviewCardsDataAdapter mCardAdapter;
    com.wenchao.cardstack.CardStack mCardStack;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preview_song, container, false);
        mCardStack = (CardStack)view.findViewById(R.id.cardstackcontainer);
        mCardStack.setContentResource(R.layout.song_preview_card_layout);
        mCardStack.setStackMargin(20);

        new getSongsInCategory().execute();

        return view;
    }

    public class getSongsInCategory extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

            SongDatabaseMappingAdapter songs = new SongDatabaseMappingAdapter();
            songs.setCategory("Rap");

            String userRatingQueryString = "5";

            Condition rangeKeyCondition = new Condition()
                    .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
                    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withN(userRatingQueryString));

            DynamoDBQueryExpression queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression()
                    .withHashKeyValues(songs)
                    .withIndexName("Category-UserRating-index")
                    .withRangeKeyCondition("UserRating", rangeKeyCondition)
                    .withConsistentRead(false);

        return mapper.query(SongDatabaseMappingAdapter.class, queryExpression);

        }

      @Override
      public void onPostExecute(Object obj){

        //Here array will not be null.

       PaginatedQueryList<SongDatabaseMappingAdapter> result=(PaginatedQueryList<SongDatabaseMappingAdapter>)obj;
         mCardAdapter = new SongPreviewCardsDataAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),result[0]);
        mCardAdapter.add("test1");

        mCardStack.setAdapter(mCardAdapter);

        }

    }
```